# accessing object in a variable using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access the values of the object properties from the variable below except the songs property using ng-repeat.

`var albumPicasso = {
     title: 'The Colors',
     artist: 'Pablo Picasso',
     label: 'Cubism',
     year: '1881',
     albumArtUrl: 'assets/images/album_covers/01.png',
     songs: [
         { title: 'Blue', duration: '4:05', audioUrl: 'assets/music/blue' },
         { title: 'Green', duration: '5:05', audioUrl: 'assets/music/green' },
         { title: 'Red', duration: '3:45', audioUrl: 'assets/music/red' },
         { title: 'Pink', duration: '4:05', audioUrl: 'assets/music/pink' },
         { title: 'Magenta', duration: '4:03', audioUrl: 'assets/music/magenta' }
     ]
 };`

here's what my controller.js looks like in my album.js:

```
(function(){
  function AlbumCtrl(){
    this.albumData = albumPicasso;
  }
  angular
    .module('blocJams')
    .controller('AlbumCtrl', AlbumCtrl)

})();
```

and below is my html where I was trying to access the values using ng-repeat and it doesn't work I don't see any output at all

```
<div class="album-view-details column half" ng-repeat="x in album.albumData">
           <h2 class="album-view-title">{{x.title}}</h2>
           <h3 class="album-view-artist">{{x.artist}}</h3>
           <h5 class="album-view-release-info">{{x.year}}</h5>
         </div>
```

Comment: Maybe if you transform your object into an array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one object you do not need `ng-repeat`. You can reference the properties by doing `{{this.albumData.title}}`.`ng-repeat` is used with arrays.

Also if it is an array, in your `ng-repeat` I'm not sure where the word `album` in `album.albumData` is coming from, you may want to use `this.albumData`.

Answer (score 0):

ngRepeat requires a collection.

**[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):**

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given
>   loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index is set
>   to the item index or key.

You can print directly the values of the object properties `albumPicasso` `(title, artits, label, year)` with:

```
<h2 class="album-view-title">{{albumData.title}}</h2>
      <h3 class="album-view-artist">{{albumData.artist}}</h3>
      <h5 class="album-view-release-info">{{albumData.year}}</h5>
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  function AlbumCtrl($scope) {
    var albumPicasso = {
      title: 'The Colors',
      artist: 'Pablo Picasso',
      label: 'Cubism',
      year: '1881',
      albumArtUrl: 'assets/images/album_covers/01.png',
      songs: [{
          title: 'Blue',
          duration: '4:05',
          audioUrl: 'assets/music/blue'
        },
        {
          title: 'Green',
          duration: '5:05',
          audioUrl: 'assets/music/green'
        },
        {
          title: 'Red',
          duration: '3:45',
          audioUrl: 'assets/music/red'
        },
        {
          title: 'Pink',
          duration: '4:05',
          audioUrl: 'assets/music/pink'
        },
        {
          title: 'Magenta',
          duration: '4:03',
          audioUrl: 'assets/music/magenta'
        }
      ]
    };
    $scope.albumData = albumPicasso;
  }
  angular
    .module('blocJams', [])
    .controller('AlbumCtrl', AlbumCtrl);


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="blocJams">
  <div data-ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
    <div class="album-view-details column half">
      <h2 class="album-view-title">{{albumData.title}}</h2>
      <h3 class="album-view-artist">{{albumData.artist}}</h3>
      <h5 class="album-view-release-info">{{albumData.year}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```